# jquery scroller with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap framework and use this plugin for the div scrollbar http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

if you click on the tab 1 the div with content will be there. but the problem is it will not show the scrollbar, if you minimize the screen, the scrollbar will show.

jquery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar({
        scrollButtons:{
        enable:true
    }
});
```

any Idea how scrollbar will be active on load?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of advanced options you could play with, try to enable/disable them until you get what you want, one of these is

```
advanced: {
    updateOnContentResize: Boolean
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used that plugin but a common issue with scrollbars are elements not having set height or content to set enough height to display the scrollbar. Reading their documentation they mention the following:

"Your .content element(s) (or any other element you’re attaching the custom scrollbar) should have a typical styling of an overflowed block, e.g. a height (or max-height) value, overflow: auto (or hidden) and its content should be long enough to require a scrollbar."

Something like:

to test CSS:

```
    #content_1 {
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content_1">
  <p>Content Here....</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is
Some browsers like Chrome &FF didnt show scrollbar if it is not necessory or no need to show it
that is the content is exactly matches or less than the window size.
what you can try
if your window is maximised, decrease its size until there is a need for scrolling
try another browsers